# Recyclerview rebound animation

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-recyclerview

i added rebound animation to all item which is a row of recylerview. But the animation is beginning when the rows is appeared. How can i start animation when the scroll event is stopped?

Any idea?

i am calling below method in the `onbindviewholder` like that:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    //some codes here

    setReboundAnimationtoProfilePicture(holder.image5IV);

    }

   private void setReboundAnimationtoProfilePicture(ImageView imageView){
    SpringSystem springSystem;
    Spring mScaleSpring;
    SpringConfig config;

    springSystem = SpringSystem.create();
    //config       = SpringConfig.defaultConfig;
    mScaleSpring = springSystem.createSpring();

    Crashlytics.log(Log.ASSERT, "velocity ", mScaleSpring.getVelocity() +"");

    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomTension   = rand.nextInt((40 - 28) + 1) + 28;
    int randomFriction  = rand.nextInt((25 - 15) + 1) + 15;

    //config.tension = 40;
    //config.friction = 5;


    SpringListener mSpringListener = new SpringListener(imageView);
    mScaleSpring.addListener(mSpringListener);
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.post(new myRunnable(mScaleSpring, handler));



}
```

Spring Listener

```
private class SpringListener extends SimpleSpringListener {

    private ImageView imageView;

    public SpringListener(ImageView imageView){

        this.imageView = imageView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onSpringUpdate(Spring spring) {
        float mappedValue = (float) SpringUtil.mapValueFromRangeToRange(spring.getCurrentValue(), 0, 1, 1, 0.5);
        imageView.setScaleX(mappedValue);
        imageView.setScaleY(mappedValue);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the code where you add the animation.

Comment: @Buddy I added the code. I am using facebookspring library for it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use [onScrollListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.OnScrollListener.html#onScrollStateChanged(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView,%20int)) and to soemthing like this :

```
RecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
   public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
       //Is scrolling
   }

   public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
       if (scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
           //Start animation
       }
}});
```

Comment: I am starting animation in adapter class(i added the code block in my question). So how can i start recylerview item's animation from fragment? @Skizo

Comment: @AliGürelli Solved it ?

Comment: Yes but i used different solution to for it.

Comment: Oh... So shall I delete my answer? Or it helped to you?

Comment: that can be helpful for another users :)